# WPF and SQLite 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: conn' on SchemaExport NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

WPF application allows users to generate SQLite databased. Randomly I'm getting error on creating database. I'm using fluent mapping.

Error as below. PontentialReasons is empty.

> An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

Inner expection:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: conn

Stack Trace:

```
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.CloseConnection(DbConnection conn)
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.CloseConnection(DbConnection conn)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.InitConnectionAndExecute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean execute, Boolean justDrop, DbConnection connection, TextWriter exportOutput)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Boolean useStdOut, Boolean execute, Boolean justDrop)
   at DatabaseOperations.DbManager.BuildSchema(Configuration config)
```

- Projects are compiled to x86,
- System.Data.Sqlite, System.DataSqlite.Core, System.DataSqlite.EF6
  System.DataSqlite.Linq v1.0.96
- FluentNhibernate v3.1.0
- Nhibernate 5.3.8

Error occurs on schema.Execute line (schema object is created):

```
        private void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
        {
            try
            {

                // disable proxy validator in order to apply INotifyPropertyChanged  
                config.Properties.Add("use_proxy_validator", "false");
                config.Properties.Add("current_session_context_class", "thread_static");
                if (!File.Exists(this.dbPath) || OverwriteExistingDatabase)
                {
                    config.DataBaseIntegration(x => x.Timeout = 255);
                    var schema = new SchemaExport(config);
                    schema.Execute(true, true, false);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

```
        public ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(string dbPath)
        {
            try
            {

                 config = Fluently.Configure().Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(dbPath))
                        .Mappings(m =>
                            {
                                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Fund>();
                            })
                        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema).BuildConfiguration();

#if DEBUG
                config.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
                    {
                        x.AutoCommentSql = true;
                        x.LogFormattedSql = true;
                        x.LogSqlInConsole = true;
                    });
#endif

                return  config.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, what does the inner exception say? Please provide more error details.

Comment: inner exception is just "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: conn"  which is weird as I'm trying to create db.